# Permissions to create album and upload photos to app facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an application on Facebook, and page, connected to it. There is also a web-site. Web-site have lots of photo-albums, that we'd like to transfer to Facebook app page. Plus we want to add functionality to the site, that when user uploads new photo album there, it's also created on Facebook app page. That's the only place photos will be uploaded to - no other FB pages or users, only our app page.

So far, from what I read in Facebook docs, it seems that we require two spesific permissions for this: `manage_pages` and `publish_actions`.

I tryed to request these permisssions in our FB app. Screencast was attached, showing, how user is creating an alum on our web-site, and I wrote a note, that we need these permissions to photos be also uploaded to FB.

Permissions query was rejected by FB with the following answer: `Please show the completed post on the pages timeline`. Possibly meaning, that they want to see on screen-cast, how album appears on FB app page timeline after it's created on the web-site.

I don't really understand, how this can be shown, if we do not have required permissions for this (otherwise we wouldn't request them). Maybe they mean that album should be created manualy, and then added to screencast, as if it was created programaticaly, just to make our intensions clear?

---

So, basicaly, here are two questions:

- are `manage_pages` and `publish_actions` correct and only required permissions for creating albums/uploading photos to FB app page?
- how can I show on the screen-cast, that photo album is uploaded to app page after certain actions on the web-site, if we do not have permissions to do that programmaticaly. Should album be added there maually?

---

Update for @CBroe, for our discussion in comments. 
I perform the user login in the following way:

```
const loginOptions = {
    scope: 'publish_pages,manage_pages', 
    return_scopes: true
};

$(document).on('click', '.facebook-login', function(e) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        //...
    }, loginOptions);
});
```

I'm not asked about permissions in login modal window. After this, if I check my permissions with `me/permissions`, I see, that required permissions are granted. But still, when I try to create an album with post query to `pageId + '/albums'`, I receive the following message: `(#10) Application does not have permission for this action`.

By the way, I'm testing this not on production app, but on it's test version. But I suppose it should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the process. Any user with a role in your app - admin, developer, tester - can be asked for any permission *without review*; explicitly so that you can build and test your app properly, before you submit it for review.

This is also an - intended - "loophole" around the review process, if your app is not intended for use by the general public. So if you only want this app to post to your page in the name of the page (the album and photos will appear as created/uploaded and owned by the page, not the Facebook user profile belonging to the user of your app) - then only you, or a page admin that you add to one of the roles in your app, needs to grant those permissions, and therefor you don't even have to get it reviewed. (Not at least regarding those two permissions, for the intended purpose. If your app requests other permissions from general users for a different purpose, those still need to be reviewed.)

This is explained in the App Development FAQ: [My app is only used by a small number of people, who are all listed in the Role section of the App Dashboard - do I need to go through Login Review?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921)

---

(If you want the albums created and the photos to be posted in the name of the FB user profile of your app users, then things are different - then you need to get the functionality reviewed of course. Not sure if users can even create albums on pages though, or whether they are only able to post to existing ones, you'd have to check.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I got the general point, but still not everything is clear. What do you mean by `Any user with a role in your app - admin, developer, tester - can be asked for any permission`. maybe I again misunderstood smth. How can I ask a user for permissions?

I'm asking... the facebook system, by quering to `oauth/access_token` with some set of permissions to be granted... That is also not clear from FAQ question you pointed me to.

Comment: _"How can I ask a user for permissions?"_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: Ah, I get it. Well, that does not really work. I do a login, requesting these two permissions, but they are declined. Maybe it's because they have such status on app permissions page, as I submited them for review? To @CBroe

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "declined"? Does the user not get asked for them on the login dialog?

Comment: Firstly, he is not asked for them, there is just login form. Secondly, when I check his allowed permissions after login, by querying to `/me/permissions`, these two are returned with `declined` status. @CBroe

Comment: I added login code to the issue (also accidentaly added it to your answer - deep night in here, feel sleepy) @CBroe

Comment: Well, they ARE granted, but still I can not create an album. Added this in details to issue. @CBroe

Comment: Hei @CBroe, I've added some details to issue. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sounds like you are not using a page access token for the POST request to create the album, but a user access token.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! That was one last missing thing. It works now!